# Crud for users via an admin controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently developing a .net MVC app using the built in authentication system for users. What I want is for a site administrator to be able to log in, list all registered users and have the ability to edit and create users. Each user will have a role.

I have the following action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        return View(users);
    }
```

which lets me display the users but it does not provide access to a userID to pass through to an edit/create action. Nor does it give access to a role (I have set up a role the configuration tool). I'm a .MVC noob so please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

James

Comment: you could learn something from http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/user (from the source code)

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary for you to build an app to manage web site administration? There are apps such as http://wsat.codeplex.com/ which could achieve your objective.

If you need to roll out a custom app, I'd make it role-based. That is check if current user has an admin role and then redirect user to perform the CRUD operations. Something akin to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step4

BTW, you may need to consider that GetAllUsers would slow up your app, if there are a lot of users to manage.